# Extract the complete list of file extensions from a directory

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I have a directory with lot of sub directories in multiple level and I want to extract the unique list of file extensions that are present in all these sub directories.

Is there a simple way to do it from command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your definition of "extension" is "anything after the last dot, or else nothing" then maybe something like

```
find dir -name '*.*' -print | rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev
```

Pipe into `| sort -u` to get just the unique extensions.

This is not robust against file names with newlines in them, etc.

The concept of a "file extension" is not well formalized on Unix, but if you are traversing e.g. a web server's files (which often do depend on an extension scheme) this should work.

Comment: I didn't know about the `rev` command before. Seems to be really useful command to know.

Comment: Actually I think @fedorqui's Awk solution is kinda elegant (-:

Comment: I agree. It is just that I had lot of files without extension and the `awk` command ended up treating all of them as unique file extensions.

Comment: Good one! In fact, I think the `-print` part in `find` is not necessary.

Comment: It's required for portability, but GNU `find` does not require it.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example do:

```
find /your/dir -type f | awk -F. '{a[$NF]} END{for (i in a) print i}'
```

- `find /your/dir -type f` finds files
- `awk -F. '{a[$NF]} END{for (i in a) print i}'` gets all the extensions and prints them.

Comment: This works. But I am choosing @tripleee answer because that works even when some files don't have file extensions. But upvoted.

Comment: No problem, his solution is very nice! In case you want to skip files without extension, you can use what tripleee used in find: `-name '*.*'`